# Mapbox load surrounding tiles

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Is it possible to specify in Javascript to load surrounding tiles using Mapbox like google maps does? If so, how?

It looks rather glitchy every time you pan the map it only then starts loading the necessary tiles.

I cannot show you my app, but if you look at this Mapbox map example the same problem can be found here: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/ilyakar.i68649in/page.html?secure=1#14/50.0875/14.4152.

Foursquare uses Mapbox as well, somehow they eliminated this problem..

Answer (score 1):

You are using v3 of the api - have you tried to upgrade to v4 of the api?

"Check your code to see if you’re requesting v3. If you’re still using v3, you’ll need to update to v4. In addition to changing the version number, you’ll also need to pass one of your access tokens with the request."

Re: https://www.mapbox.com/help/blank-tiles/